# Python Loop inside a def

Tags: python, python-3.x, moviepy

I'm stuck in a Python script.
The Store: I have a folder "Recordings" with *.h264 files.
Now I want the files to be converted into *.mp4 files. That part works good.
But when in this folder are several *.h264 files, this script breaks. Says it can't find the file I deleted.

So my question is, can this script run the def Convert_File() in a loop, till all files are converted? Or should I make several .py files. For instance "convert.py" and "show_clips.py" and bring it all together in a "start.py"?

This is my code:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import glob
import os.path
import subprocess
from time import sleep

#Variabels
folder_path = r'/home/pi/Halloween/Recordings'                                             #path to videofiles
file_type = r'/*h264'                                                                          #extension of the recordings
file_type_conv = r'/*mp4'                                                                      #extension added after convertion
files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)                                                     #creates complete path for *.h264 
files_conv = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type_conv)                                           #creates complete path for *.mp4
clip_show = sorted(glob.iglob(r'/home/pi/Halloween/Recordings/*'),key=os.path.getctime)    #sorts files by date


#Functions
def Convert_File():
    if glob.glob(folder_path + file_type):                                                     #if there is a *.h264
        print('Yes there is')
        clip_latest = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)                                         #sort the files by cdate
        clip_conv = clip_latest + '.mp4'                                                       #adds extension behind file
        print(clip_latest)
        print(clip_conv)
        subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', clip_latest, clip_conv])                               #convert from h264 to mp4
        os.remove(clip_latest)                                                                 #remove the 264 file
        print('converted')
    else:
        print('nothing converted')                                                             #no h264 - noting done


#Show Clips
def Show_Clips():
        clip1 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-1]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip2 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-2]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip3 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-3]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip4 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-4]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip5 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-5]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip6 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-6]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip7 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-7]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip8 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-8]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip9 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-9]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip10 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-10]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip11 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-11]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip12 = VideoFileClip(clip_show [-12]).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        

        combined = clips_array([[clip1, clip2, clip3],
                                [clip4, clip5, clip6]])

                                
        combined.preview(audio=False, fps=25)
        sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        while True:
                try:
                        Convert_File()
                        Show_Clips()
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                        break
```

I tried to enter "Covert_File()" before "else:"
But that did not work.

Hope that someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import glob
import os.path
import subprocess
from time import sleep

# Variables
folder_path = r'/home/pi/Halloween/Recordings'
file_type = r'/*.h264'
file_type_conv = r'/*.mp4'

# Functions
def Convert_File():
    h264_files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
    if h264_files:
        for clip_latest in h264_files:
            clip_conv = clip_latest + '.mp4'
            subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', clip_latest, clip_conv])
            os.remove(clip_latest)
            print(f'Converted {clip_latest} to {clip_conv}')
    else:
        print('No .h264 files to convert.')

def Show_Clips():
    clip_show = sorted(glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.*')), key=os.path.getctime)
    clips = []

    for clip_path in clip_show[-12:]:
        clip = VideoFileClip(clip_path).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clips.append(clip)

    combined = clips_array([[clips[i] for i in range(j, j + 3)] for j in range(0, len(clips), 3)])
    combined.preview(audio=False, fps=25)
    sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            Convert_File()
            Show_Clips()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And you cleaned up the code. Thank you! The only thing what is see is that the preview contains different sizes of the clips. Can the clips be resized?

Comment: You can set the variables inside Show_Clips() like:
    target_width = 640
    target_height = 480

And then before appending 'clips.append(clip)' add below code:
clip = clip.resize((target_width, target_height))

 Adjust the target_width and target_height values to fit your preferred size.

Comment: I can't get it to work. I keep getting a AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute "ANTIALIAS'.  I've put the targets under "clips=[]" and the clip.resize above the clips.append().  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by (under "clips=[]"). Please share that piece of code. It will be helpful for me to check and provide solution quickly

Comment: `def Show_Clips():
    clip_show = sorted(glob.iglob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*.*')), key=os.path.getctime)
    clips = []
    target_width = 180
    target_height = 120

    for clip_path in clip_show[-12:]:
        clip = VideoFileClip(clip_path).subclip(0, 1).margin(3)
        clip = clip.resize((target_width, target_height))
        clips.append(clip)`

Comment: Got it. the problem is not the code. It's inside Pillow 10 that doesn't support 'ANTIALIAS' anymore. Moviepy looks for Opencv first to resize, if not installed it will look at ANTIALIAS. So I installed Opencv-Python (sudo apt install python3-opencv) and everything works now.